# Adding Struct to Array - Invalid OpCode - Solidity 0.6

Tags: arrays, struct, solidity-0.6.x

I've been wreaking my brain on this for a while, could use some help. Bottomline, the `newProposal` function throws an `VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode` error. The puzzling thing is that this function was working fine with Solidity 0.5, but not with 0.6. Here is what I've attempted so far, any further insight is greatly appreciated.

1. According to the [breaking changes](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/060-breaking-changes.html) in Solidity 0.6, I suspect that the issue is about the resizing of the `proposals` array to add a new `Proposal` struct, which is somewhat supported by [this issue](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79169/invalid-opcode-exception-when-trying-to-resize-a-storage-array).

- *Member-access to length of arrays is now always read-only, even for storage arrays. It is no longer possible to resize storage arrays by assigning a new value to their length. Use push(), push(value) or pop() instead, or assign a full array, which will of course overwrite the existing content. The reason behind this is to prevent storage collisions of gigantic storage arrays.*

So I have attempted a number of variations here (i.e., `proposals.push()`, hard coding `proposalID`). No luck. I don't believe the struct and its properties are the problem, but I can't be 100% sure of that either. So I feel like I'm missing something relatively obvious here, and I thank you for any assistance.

The function that returns an `invalid opCode` error

```js
    /**
     * Add Proposal
     *
     * Propose to send `weiAmount / 1e18` ether to `beneficiary` for `jobDescription`. `transactionBytecode ? Contains : Does not contain` code.
     *
     * @param beneficiary who to send the ether to
     * @param weiAmount amount of ether to send, in wei
     * @param jobDescription Description of job
     * @param transactionBytecode bytecode of transaction
     */
    function newProposal(
        address beneficiary,
        uint weiAmount,
        string memory jobDescription,
        bytes memory transactionBytecode
    )
        public onlyShareholders
        returns (uint proposalID)
    {
        proposalID = proposals.length+1; //I suspect the problem is here...
        // I've tried proposals.push(); proposalID = proposals.length; instead, no luck
        Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalID]; //...or here
        p.recipient = beneficiary;
        p.amount = weiAmount;
        p.description = jobDescription;
        p.proposalHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(beneficiary, weiAmount, transactionBytecode));
        p.minExecutionDate = now + debatingPeriodInMinutes * 1 minutes;
        p.executed = false;
        p.proposalPassed = false;
        p.numberOfVotes = 0;
        emit ProposalAdded(proposalID, beneficiary, weiAmount, jobDescription);
        numProposals = proposalID+1;

        return proposalID;
    }
```

The `Proposal` struct and `proposals` array

```js
    Proposal[] public proposals;

    struct Proposal {
        address recipient;
        uint amount;
        string description;
        uint minExecutionDate;
        bool executed;
        bool proposalPassed;
        uint numberOfVotes;
        bytes32 proposalHash;
        Vote[] votes;
        mapping (address => bool) voted;
    }
```

EDIT: This fixed it, see comments below with @goodvibration

```js
proposalID = proposals.length;
proposals.push();
Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalID];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously trying to access the array at an illegal index:

```
proposalID = proposals.length+1;
Proposal storage p = proposals[proposalID];
```

Valid indexes in any `array` are between `0` and `array.length - 1`.

Most people get it wrong trying to access the `array` at `array.length`.

You got it wrong trying to access the `array` at `array.length + 1`!

---

Note that trying to access `array` using `array.length` or higher is designated to fail **by definition** no matter how many elements you push into `array` beforehand, because while pushing those elements, `array.length` grows along with it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, arrays are zero indexed, however the intent here is to resize the array in order to add the Proposal struct. I've attempted a number of different variations here, all resulting in the same problem (i.e., `proposals.push(); proposalID = proposals.length;`). Same error. How would you re-write this in order to add the Proposal struct to the array?

Comment: @FugueWeb: With `proposals[proposalID]`, you are not resizing the array, you are accessing it!

Comment: @FugueWeb: And no matter how many items you push into it, if at the end of the day you try to access it using its own length or higher (for example, `arr[arr.length]`), then your code is designated for failure, as `arr.length` has grown with your array (i.e., it is an illegal index **by definition**).

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me arrive at the solution. What threw me is that this was valid in Solidity 0.5 (i.e., `proposalID = proposals.length++`), but as noted in the 0.6 changelog it is no longer possible to resize storage arrays by assigning a new value to their length.

Comment: @FugueWeb: You're welcome. And BTW, there's no `proposalID = proposals.length++` in your code anyway. One could indeed wonder what the problem was in that case. But you wrote `proposalID = proposals.length+1`, which clearly leads to an error. Please accept the answer if it has answered your question.

Comment: Accepted. For my edification, isn't arr.length++ and arr.length+1 the same thing? The former was throwing an error in my IDE when I changed to 0.6, hence why I wrote it as +1.

Comment: @FugueWeb: No. Postfix `++` returns the value of the operand **prior** to incrementing it.